# Por que não é recomendado usar DefaultTableModel?

Tags: java, swing

Pesquisei em alguns sites sobre como fazer o preenchimento de uma table em java e em muitos foi sugerido que evitasse o [`DefaultTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)?

Por que deve-se evitar utilizar esta classe para casos de objetos mais complexos? O que implica no seu uso?

Answer (score 2):

Este [site](http://matheuspiscioneri.com.br/blog/nao-use-defaulttablemodel-e-sim-abstracttablemodel/) (Matheus Piscioneri) resumiu muito bem os motivos.

- É mais difícil que escrever seu próprio TableModel *(fato)*;
- É mais lento (usa classes sincronizadas) (se olhar o código verá que a classe utiliza `Vector` e não `List`);
- Ocupa mais espaço em memória (duplica seus dados) *(Ainda não consegui testar)* ;
- Deixa o código mais confuso e difícil de manter *(fato)*;
- Usa casts inseguros (por exemplo no método `convertToVector(Object[] anArray)` onde : `Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>(anArray.length);`

  ```
  for (Object o : anArray) {
      v.addElement(o);
  };
  ```
- Força que você tenha que exibir informações desnecessárias (como o ID) na  tabela, ou controlar o ID numa lista separada;
- *Faz a sua mulher te deixar, o leite da sua geladeira azedar, e pessoas apontarem o dedo para você na rua.(Isso realmente aconteceu);*

Uma prática que **ViniGodoy** sempre recomendou.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente, o uso do DefaultTable é mais complicado. E manutenção acaba sendo mais demorada também.

Quando estava vendo sobre isso, usei esse exemplo e me ajudou a entender mto bem.

Talvez possa te ajudar.

```
package nome_do_pacote;
import br.com.agenda.modelo.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
public class ContatoTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    public static final int COLUNA_CODIGO = 0;
    public static final int COLUNA_NOME = 1;
    public static final int COLUNA_EMAIL = 2;
    public static final int COLUNA_FIXO = 3;
    public static final int COLUNA_CELULAR = 4;
    private List<Contato> listarContatos;
public ContatoTableModel(List<Contato> l){
    this.listarContatos = new ArrayList<Contato>(l);
}
public int getRowCount(){
    return listarContatos.size();
}
public int getColumnCount(){
    return 5;
}
public Object getValueAt(int linhas, int colunas){
    Contato cont  = this.listarContatos.get(linhas);
    if(colunas == COLUNA_CODIGO) return cont.getCodigo();
    if(colunas == COLUNA_NOME) return cont.getNome();
    if(colunas == COLUNA_EMAIL) return cont.getEmail();
    if(colunas == COLUNA_FIXO) return cont.getFixo();
    if(colunas == COLUNA_CELULAR) return cont.getCelular();
    return "";
}
public String getColumnName(int colunas){
    if(colunas == COLUNA_CODIGO) return "Código";
    if(colunas == COLUNA_NOME) return "Nome";
    if(colunas == COLUNA_EMAIL) return "E-mail";
    if(colunas == COLUNA_FIXO) return "Telefone";
    if(colunas == COLUNA_CELULAR) return "Celular";
    return "";
}
public Contato get(int linhas){
    return listarContatos.get(linhas);
}
}
```

O DefaultTable está no site da Oracle, se fosse tão ruim assim, não estaria lá. Para quem é iniciante, acho simples utilizar usando IDE como o netbeans por exemplo.

Sem fanatismo :)